# Why doesn't isalpha() work for sanitizing user input?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

The trouble I'm having here is that the `isalpha()` function isn't doing what it's supposed to do, users are able to send messages that contain characters that are not alphabetical. I'm not sure why this occurs. I assumed that it was some kind of hosting issue (which from the looks of it wasn't) prior to assuming that there was a logical error in my code, but logically it makes sense to me which perhaps is wrong? I kinda also made the assumption that it had to do with the function not being asynchronous, I don't know I probably am reaching with that one.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import re


class Shiritori(commands.Cog):
    """ Start a new word from the last letter of the one before. """

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.repeats = re.compile(r'(.)\1{2,}')  # Matches spam like 'eeeeeee'
        self.shiritori_channel = 578788555120312330  # Official

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        try:
            if message.channel.id == self.shiritori_channel:
                previous_message = (await message.channel.history(limit=2).flatten())[1].content

                repeats_mo = self.repeats.search(message.content)
                if not repeats_mo and message.content.isalpha():
                    if previous_message[-1].lower() != message.content[0].lower():
                        await message.author.send(
                            f'Your message must start with the last letter of the latest message!')
                        await message.delete()
                else:
                    await message.author.send("You can't do that here!")
                    await message.delete()
        except discord.Forbidden:
            await message.delete()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are expecting that any non-ascii English character is not alpha.

But

According to the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha),

> str.isalpha() Return True if all characters in the string are
> alphabetic and there is at least one character, False otherwise.
> Alphabetic characters are those characters defined in the Unicode
> character database as “Letter”, i.e., those with general category
> property being one of “Lm”, “Lt”, “Lu”, “Ll”, or “Lo”. Note that this
> is different from the “Alphabetic” property defined in the Unicode
> Standard.

So for example `à` (french a) or `любовь` are also considered `alpha`

```
'à'.isalpha()
True
'любовь'.isalpha()
True
```

If you want the english letters, use `isascii()`:

```
'à'.isascii()
False
```